# Installing Docker on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

Following [AWS instruction to install Docker](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html), After ssh to the ubuntu instance, I am getting the terminal as
`ubuntu@ip-<private ip>:~$` but step 3 says
`[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum update -y`

Not sure if I should continue wit the command or I need to create a user and re login as that user? I am new to AWS and my linux practice is 10 years old.

And if a user needs to be created, is that via the current ssh or the AWS console?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation shows how to install Docker on Amazon Linux instances not ubuntu. The user youre logged in with doesnt matter, just replace the yum commands with the apt-get equivalents or switch to using an Amazon Linux AMI.

Answer (score 1):

You use simple curl command to install docker on any Linux machine.

**curl -SsL https://get.docker.com |  bash**

Above command will automatically solve all the dependencies and install docker.

Answer (score 0):

For **Ubuntu**, you can use:
            **$ sudo apt-get update**

you might have been checking the documentation of **RHEL** which needs 
$ sudo yum update -y

If you are working behind a **proxy**, Make sure you configure the proxy for Docker.

Hope it helps.. **:)**

Answer (score 0):

Follow below commands on ubuntu ec2 :

1. curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -;
2. sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable";
3. sudo apt-get update -y;
4. sudo apt-cache policy docker-ce;  ( Here select the required one from this step for the next step)
5. sudo apt-get install docker-ce=5:18.09.2~3-0~ubuntu-xenial;
6. sudo service docker start;